# visualizar campo de DataGridViewRow

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un DataGridViewRow en mi formulario que tiene un campo de Notas pero estas notas aveces los usuarios las escriben muy largas entonces el campo se extiende mucho ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo yo hacer un cuadro donde quepa todo este texto o la columna se expanda dependiendo el texto o me muestre un cuadro de dialogo

**modificación** 
quedo así pero se ve algo feo no hay manera de que al pasar el mouse por el campo notas salga un ventana emergente o un burbuja con el texto si la hay me pueden ayudar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `DataGridView` tiene propiedades como ser:

[DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode?view=netframework-4.8)

la cual debes cambiar para poder controlar el ancho de columnas.

Podrias definir el

[DataGridViewCellStyle.WrapMode Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode?view=netframework-4.8)

para que el contenido pase a la linea siguiente en caso de exceder el ancho fijado en la columna

Para mostrar menos informacion si notas que es muy larga la cadena podrias truncarla y asignar la propiedad

[DataGridViewCell.ToolTipText Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext?view=netframework-4.8)

de la celda, asi cuando pases el mouse sobre esta veras en un ``tooltip` la info completa.

Para truncar solo pones una cantidad fija de texto usando

```
string contenido = cadena.Substring(0, length);
```

en `length` defines el valor numerico del largo que consideres adecuado

Comment: Puedes mirar como me quedo y si me puedes responder la pregunta gracias

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando la propiedad que podria ayudar para ver menos informacion, pero con el tooltip poder verla completa

Answer (score 2):

Debes establecer la propiedad `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` de la columna en `DataGridViewTriState.True`. Después de esto, el texto en las celdas se mostrará correctamente.

Ejemplo (`DataGridView` con una columna):

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Probando" + Environment.NewLine + "Multilinea");
```

(`Environment.NewLine` = `\r\n` en Windows)

Comment: Puedes mirar como me quedo y si me puedes responder la pregunta gracias